# Negative lookbehind work around for 'simple' regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get rid of excess dot characters in a string. ( JavaScript )

A dot is only allowed if it matches strict rules.

**Allowed Rule: ( space or nothing)( 1 char a-z ).( space or nothing )**

if any dot in the string does not match this, the dot must be replaced by a space (only the dot).

For example "" represents string start/end:

**Illegal Examples ( MATCH )**

- `"dd."`        = match
- `"d.d"`        = match

**Allowed Examples ( no match )**

- `"d."`          = no match
- `" d."`        = no match
- `" d. "`      = no match
- `"d. "`        = no match

The closest I can get is:

```js
var string = "dd. d.d d. d. d.d d.dd";

var res = string.replace(/[.](?! |$)/g, ' ');
```

Results in: `"dd. d d d. d. d d d dd "`

If JavaScript would support negative look behind I might be able to figure it out.
Anyone have an idea how to match this correctly?

Comment: What is your expected output for `string = "dd. d.d d. d. d.d d.dd";`?

Comment: How come `dd.` is a match but `d.` isn't?

Comment: Could you provide some more multi-character examples? if you had `dd. d.d d. d. d.d d.dd`, what should it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem with a capturing group:

```
res = str.replace(/([^ ][a-z]|[^a-z]|^)\.|\.(?=[^ ])/g, '$1 ');
```

Comment: I've accepted your answer as the solution because it does exactly what I want without using additional lines of code. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/), which adds support for negative lookbehinds (amongst other things)?

Answer (score 1):

To recreate lookbehind, reverse the string and use lookahead. If you need both, consider matching the lookahead on the forward string, and the lookbehind on the reverse string and find where the matches agree.

Alternatively, since the permitted case only has one occurrence of a dot, check whether the pattern matches, and do the string replacement if not.

```
if(!RegExp.test(string)) {
    string.replace(/[.]/g, ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it a lot simpler to replace ALL `.` with spaces, then re-parse your string and add dots back in where applicable?

Comment: Thats actually a easy way to look at the problem, never thought of that. Thanks!